# Вывод звука в определённый динамик

Tags: c#

Нужно выводить звук с аудиофайла в определённое устройство вывода звука (которое в системе не является стандартным), как это сделать?

Comment: Какую библиотеку для воспроизведения используете?

Comment: @Bulson какая понадобится - такую и буду использовать

Comment: Достаточно поискать на гитхаб [например](https://github.com/AntonCholakov/MP3Player-GUI-Project)

Comment: @Bulson так, и что с этим делать? Вопрос не в том, как воспроизвети файл, а в том, как его воспроизвести в определённый динамик

Comment: https://github.com/naudio/NAudio/blob/master/Docs/EnumerateOutputDevices.md

Comment: @Bulson спасибо, разобрался